# Operating on bitmaps the C++ way

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I am looking for the best way in C++ to operate on bitmaps (not .bmp files). For example I am reading a binary file and want to decode its content by a 7-bit decoder. The C way would be using bitmasks and shift-operations, but there has to be a pretty C++ way.. Are there for example bit-streams?

Comment: C++ is C, binary operations are as low as you can go, they are the same in C++.  The C++ way would be to download and use an existing class already written.

Comment: @SPlatten C++ is *not* C. There are many small but critical parts that differs between the two languages, especially when it comes to semantics. While similar looking code *might* behave similarly in a C++ and a C program, there are also as many cases where code that looks exactly the same but which behaves differently.

Comment: @SPlatten Do you know a library having such a class?

Comment: You can write a 7-bit stream yourself in like 5 minutes, it would take a lot more time to find and integrate someone else's solution and it will probably turn out to target a subtly different use case.

Comment: @harold I know how to write a 7-bit decoder in C. Its just an example.. I am looking for a pretty C++ style solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, C++ was developed on C, I didn't elaborate, but essentially there is nothing in C that you cannot do in C++.

Comment: @Macxx, not personally. but there are lots on Google.